# access violation reading location c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that print the full english name of the number inputted by the user. it's not a complete program but i keep getting an error:

First-chance exception at 0x00b02c76 in Programming Challenge 14.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd80.
Unhandled exception at 0x00b02c76 in Programming Challenge 14.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd80.

I've tried looking around and couldn't find anything of use to me. here this the program:

header file:

```
#ifndef NUMBERS_H
#define NUMBERS_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE1 = 18;
const int SIZE2 = 8;

class Numbers
{
private:
    int number;
    string hundred;
    string thousand;
    string * one;
    string * ten;


public:
    Numbers(int num)
    {
        number = num;
        hundred = "hundred";
        thousand = "thousand";
        string * one = new string[SIZE1];
        string * ten = new string[SIZE2];
    }

    void initializeArray()
    {
        // Intialize array "one"
        one[0] = "zero";
        one[1] = "one";
        one[2] = "two";
        one[3] = "three";
        one[4] = "four";
        one[5] = "five";
        one[6] = "six";
        one[7] = "seven";
        one[8] = "eight";
        one[9] = "nine";
        one[10] = "eleven";
        one[11] = "twelve";
        one[12] = "thirteen";
        one[13] = "fourteen";
        one[14] = "fifteen";
        one[15] = "sixteen";
        one[16] = "seventeen";
        one[17] = "eighteen";
        one[18] = "nineteen";

        // Initialize the ten array

        ten[0] = "ten";
        ten[1] = "twenty";
        ten[2] = "thirty";
        ten[3] = "forty";
        ten[4] = "fifty";
        ten[5] = "sixty";
        ten[6] = "seventy";
        ten[7] = "eighty";
        ten[8] = "ninety";  
    }

    string determine()
    {
        string name = "";

        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if (number == i)
            {
                name = one[i];
            }
        }

        return name;
    }

    ~Numbers()
    {
        delete [] one;
        delete [] ten;
    }
};

#endif
```

and this is the main program, im just using a constructor to assign a value to number to make debugging a little faster

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Numbers.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{


    Numbers n(5);
    string name = n.determine();

    cout << "The number is " << name << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

by the way this is vc++ for the compiler

ill answer any questions as this isnt really too organized

Comment: Why not use a vector of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here:

You are not calling "initializeArray()" at all. So when you are trying to access the array there is nothing there. I would recommend calling it in the constructor. Like this:

```
Numbers(int num)
{
    number = num;
    hundred = "hundred";
    thousand = "thousand";
    one = new string[SIZE1];
    ten = new string[SIZE2];
    initializeArray();
}
```

Second, is what the guys above said. You have an incorrect value for the size of your array since you are trying to assign 19 values to an array of size 18. Just to be really sure lets make the size bigger than we expect and you can adjust later:

```
const int SIZE1 = 20;
const int SIZE2 = 20;
```

Additionally, See your determine()? instead of using a for loop why don't you go:

```
string name = one[number];
```

EDIT: Wow there was another thing I missed...you have declared your array pointer variable twice and so it's actually going out of scope thinking you want to make some local versions. Look at my adjusted implementation of your constructor above again. See how I've removed the "String *" from before the variable names.

Comment: I made your suggestions and it still keeps throwing the error at me, would like to see the edited code? maybe I missed something?

Comment: hmmm let me just edit my answer to make sure we are both on the same page.

Comment: Ok so did what you told me in the constructor, as for the assignment that wouldn't be including the if/else statement right? I keep getting the error, do you think it might be the destructor that im wrongly implementing?

Comment: actually i understand what you mean by modifying the determine.

Comment: I found another issue as well...noted in my edit. just loaded it into my compiler and it worked :)

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense... its finally working. the pointers being declared inside are of the scope of the constructor. Thanks a lot! its finally working. ill just need to make the program calculate up to 9999. but that shouldnt be too much of a problem

Comment: I'll figure it out on my own :)

Comment: Yah it's a good program to learn how to write. They use this for some job interview processes to check you ability in using algorithms and solving problems. good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

```
const int SIZE1 = 18;
```

Valid array index for the array of `SIZE1` are 0 to 17. In general, valid indexes for an array of size **N** are **0** to **N-1**.

I recommend using `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 2):

`one` holds 18 elements, but you put 19 elements in there.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much to the two of you ill see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The variable "one" and "ten" have been changed from string pointers to vectors holding strings. Called the initializeArray within the constructor. Changed the way the name string was being assigned the new string. Here is the working code.

```
class Numbers
{
private:
    int number;
    string hundred;
    string thousand;
    vector<string> one;
    vector<string> ten;


public:
    Numbers(int num)
    {
        number = num;
        hundred = "hundred";
        thousand = "thousand";
        initializeArray();
    }

    void initializeArray()
    {

        one.push_back("zero");
        one.push_back("one");
        one.push_back( "two");
        one.push_back("three");
        one.push_back("four");
        one.push_back("five");
        one.push_back("six");
        one.push_back("seven");
        one.push_back("eight");
        one.push_back("nine");
        one.push_back("eleven");
        one.push_back("twelve");
        one.push_back("thirteen");
        one.push_back("fourteen");
        one.push_back("fifteen");
        one.push_back("sixteen");
        one.push_back("seventeen");
        one.push_back("eighteen");
        one.push_back("nineteen");

        // Initialize the ten array

        ten.push_back("ten");
        ten.push_back("twenty");
        ten.push_back("thirty");
        ten.push_back("forty");
        ten.push_back("fifty");
        ten.push_back("sixty");
        ten.push_back("seventy");
        ten.push_back("eighty");
        ten.push_back("ninety");  
    }

    string determine()
    {
        string name("");
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if (number == i)
            {
               auto iter = one.begin();
               iter += i;
               name.assign(*iter);
            }
        }

        return name;
    }

    ~Numbers()
    {

    }
};


int main()
{

    Numbers n(5);
    string name = n.determine();

    cout << "The number is " << name << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh wow im not too familiar with vectors, i only know their basic function and purpose but im not familiar with

Comment: auto iter = one.begin();
                   iter += i;
                   name.assign(*iter);